# Jenkins git checkout on os x times out

Tags: git, jenkins

I installed Jenkins 2.13 on OS X 10.10, and tried to do a simple pipeline job to checkout a project. However, every time the checkout would fail:

```
Started by user Jason Martens
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/reponame
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (Checkout)
Entering stage Checkout
Proceeding
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username jasonmartens # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/git6625455632990755681.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:799)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1055)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned     status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    ... 13 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why is git getting stuck here? This is a very small repo, so size is not the issue in this case.

Comment: It looks like your Jenkins job can't process your Git report during 10 minutes: it often happens when your repo is large and heavy, or because of bad connection to your Git server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the x-code installed git tools use the OS X keychain to cache credentials. This, despite the credential helper being overridden by Jenkins:

```
git --version
git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
bash-3.2$ git config --local credential.helper
store
bash-3.2$ git config --global credential.helper
bash-3.2$ git config --system credential.helper
bash-3.2$ git config credential.helper
store
```

If this is run manually as the Jenkins user in the workspace, you will see this window pop up:

[image: Keychain Not Found]

The solution I used is to install the homebrew version of git:

```
brew install git
```

Then go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration and change the git command to

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```